# Dreamforce 2019 meetup

Tags: discussion

Last year we had a small meetup for our SFSE Dreamforce Attendees, this is something that has also been organized in the past couple of years as well.

Any community members assisting Dreamforce this year that would like to meetup?

Organization wise, idk if Salesforce is able to provide a space, if not, we can always check to host it somewhere within the vicinity.

Comment: This is great idea 

Comment: I'll be at DF19. I'd be happy to meetup!

Comment: I'm hoping to be there and would love to meet up again!

Comment: I would be there for the meetup if I can convince my boss to send me to DF :)

Comment: I have a free ticket... but I can't attend this year. I'm looking forward to seeing y'all for DF2020, God willing.

Comment: Missed last year's meetup due to a conflict but would love to make it to this year's!

Comment: First time going to DF and would love to meet all of you there!

Comment: Let's do it! I missed it last year but still have fond memories from our meetups from earlier years!

Comment: I would really be interested in attending and meeting up. I was at the very first one and got my SFSE t-shirt but haven't been able to make another one.

Answer (score 8):

I'd definitely like to meet up again: last year's was a nice chilled out affair compared to the craziness of the conference!

Comment: Not sure if I can make it this year, but I agree -- it felt like actually _meeting_ people (including you, Matt -- hi!).  Which led to me social-media-following them and learning some neat stuff from them over the past year.  e.g. I have PMD in VSCode and found bugs thanks to meeting Robert.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to meet the most active people on this site. And I request that we do have a face-to-face roundtable discussion on closing questions prematurely.

Comment: you should probably open another meta discussion  simply to define what you mean by prematurely alongside some sample questions closed that best fit your definition =)